# Сделать прозрачным только фон

Tags: html, css

Есть стиль:

```
.wrapper {
background: url("images/background.png") repeat;
padding: 1px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-top: 20px;
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

И разметка вида

```
<div class="wrapper">
тут мое содержимое
</div>
```

Я хочу сделать, чтобы `background` - то есть фон, в этом стиле был полупрозрачный. 
Добавляю в стиль

```
opacity: 0.5;
```

И получается, что он становится полупрозрачный, но и вместе с этим все, что находится в этом стиле, становится тоже полупрозрачным!

Comment: а использовать background: rgba - ?

Comment: @soledar10 так в вопросе картинка фоном идет

Comment: @korytoff не заметил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить ещё один div. И изменить его z-index, чтобы держался, как фон.

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.bg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/800/600") center;
    opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: Мое мнение лучше используовать :after or :before  вместо лишнего div . Но это вам решать

Comment: @soledar10, буду благодарен, если проаргументируете.

Comment: При использовании псевдо-элементов :after и :before вы в состоянии изменять HTML разметку с помощью лишь CSS, не добавляя дополнительных элементов в HTML, при этом получаете более чистый код разметки, который выглядит визуально лучше. (Это мое субъективное мнение, а вообще это личное дело каждого, что и как и использовать)

Comment: На самом деле, и с div вам не придётся ничего менять в HTML. Насчёт чистоты - да, в каком-то смысле чище. Ещё интересна производительность.

Comment: вот ваш код с псевдоэлементом - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ybehhLkc/

Answer (score 2):

Например через псевдо элемент `:before` и абсолютное позиционирование

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px; /* for test */
}
.wrapper:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('https://xakep.ru/wp-content/uploads/post/58315/osx6.png');
  opacity: .2;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  тут мое содержимое
</div>
```

Comment: не работает это

Comment: @Денис что именно не работает?
Вот скрин http://joxi.ru/Y2Lq3ZqhvYydA6

Comment: получается что блок `wrapper` затягивает красным полупрозрачным фоном. но прозоачность фоновой картинки блока не изменяется

Comment: @Денис Изменил фон в ответе на картинку, где прозрачность не меняется?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите так

```css
body{
    background: url('https://im3-tub-kz.yandex.net/i?id=9d3490571d4f855b0197cd7f7b783a40&n=33&h=190&w=338') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
}
.wrapper:before{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: "";
    background: url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzEA1o_7CtF6NJtJ_hgz-j4TrjGFh_CiVnAHFGmwoXy_GBqRrylw');
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.default{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 30px;
  float: left;
  color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzEA1o_7CtF6NJtJ_hgz-j4TrjGFh_CiVnAHFGmwoXy_GBqRrylw');
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
     тут мое содержимое
</div>
<div class="default">
     default мое содержимое
</div>
```